# reduce list in Specman like in Python

Tags: reduce, specman

Is there a `reduce()` list method in Specman that I can use for general reduction functions?  I'm thinking of something like:

```
var x: list of bit = some_function_that_returns_list_of_bit;
var bitmap: uint = x.reduce(foo());
```

where `reduce()` works like in Python:

```
foo(last: uint, val: bit) is: uint {
    return (last << 1 ) | bit;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specman 6.1 docs don't show a reduce pseudo-method.  For your *specific* example, you can acheive what you want with:

```
bitmap = pack(packing.low, x)
```

You may find the "reduce" psuedo-method in your version of Specman by searching "List Pseudo-Methods" in your docs.

Section "Math and Logic Pseudo-Methods" shows methods and_all(), average(), or_all(), product(), and sum().  I know this is not the meta-solution, but its better than a kick in the teeth.